# CSS animation prevents subsequently styling the animated properties

Tags: css, animation

In [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/688zswcv/), there are two blocks, `.parent` and `.child`.

- `.child` animates in, using a CSS animation to change its Y position and `opacity`
- After 3 seconds, a new class is applied to the body. This changes `.child`s `background-color` and `opacity`.

However only the `background-color` actually appears to change. In other words, animating a property with the CSS animation seems to prevent subsequent styling of that property.

**How can I change the opacity on the `.child` block after it has been animated?**

**edit:** Since @srekoble's workaround is the closest thing to an answer I'll mark as it as accepted. **If anyone else finds out why the behaviour occurs, though, feel free to add an answer.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution would be to use a keyframe again for the opacity property like the following:

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    to {
        opacity: .5;
    }
}
```

example : http://jsfiddle.net/688zswcv/2/

It's a strange issue however.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use:

```
.newstate .child{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
}
```

You set your color to blue and your opacity to 0.5.

Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/688zswcv/3/

Comment: Smart solution, but he can't handle the opacity of every `child` childs elements. GJ although!

Comment: Exactly as @srekoble said - opacity and alpha on a background color aren't the same.